# Basic php Regex Help for changing url structure

Tags: php, regex

I have an image that is of the form:

http://sub-domain.example.net/random-folder-here/4422414324235_4234234.jpg

and I would like to add a folder in the middle of the url like this (s720x720 added)

http://sub-domain.example.net/random-folder-here/s720x720/4422414324235_4234234.jpg

How do I run a regex call in php that will help me do this? 
Thanks!

Comment: You don't need regex, [substr](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('![^/]+$!', 's720x720/$0', $str);
```

Comment: `[^/]` means anything but `/`, `+` means 1 or more, `$` means end of line, and the `!` are the delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add `s720x720` between the *dirname* and the *basename* (if taken the URL as a path). PHP has a function to out the URI apart here (see [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo)):

```
$url = 'http://sub-domain.example.net/random-folder-here/4422414324235_4234234.jpg';
vprintf("%s/s720x720/%s", pathinfo($url));
```

Output:

```
http://sub-domain.example.net/random-folder-here/s720x720/4422414324235_4234234.jpg
```

I hope this helps. There is not always a need to use regular expressions. Other functions can be more fitting.